# How to insert Figure beside Text

Tags: memoir, wrapfigure

As shown in attached

I am using memoir class to create my book.

What is the code should be?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Please provide a full MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: The `wrapfig` or `cutwin` packages can be used for this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I didn't know about `cutwin`. Interesting...

Comment: Thank you so much. I will work with wrapfig or cutwin package. 
Thanks Guido  for your advice.

Comment: With no MWE, this really looks unclear.