# Can I have a tcolorbox behave like wrapfig, without using the wrapfig package?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, wrapfigure, wrap

I want to have the text go on the right side of my tcolorbox (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113126/how-to-insert-figure-beside-text)), instead of it just being white space on the right side of my tcolorbox.

This code illustrates a tcolorbox with all white on the right side:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Furst}
\subsection{Ok}

%Defining a newtcolorbox to be a standard box for all examples in the text:
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{phbox}[1][]{skin=bicolor,title=Figure~\thetcbcounter,#1,size=title,colback=white,colbacklower=black!10!white}


Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
\begin{phbox}[label={fig:label},halign=center,width=\linewidth/2]
\tcbincludepdf[scale=1,size=tight,opacityframe=0]{example-image.pdf}
\tcblower
Here is a bunch of text to explain a figure.
\end{phbox}
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere 


\end{document}
```

I've tried using `nobeforeafter` and `after=,` in the tcolorbox options, but this does not produce the desired effect. My best guess is a solution using `before` and `after`, I've tried looking in the manual for clues, but I've come up empty.

Do I have to use the `wrapfig` package to achieve this? I would prefer a way to do it with `tcolorbox`.

Thanks!

**Edit**: To clarify: Before using a new package, I wanted to make sure that there wasn't an obvious easy way to do it using `tcolorbox`. The thing I'm asking for seems like it should be easy to do, maybe it was too obvious for the manual.

I'm already using a lot of tcolorbox in my document, and it's a lot more work having to put stuff in a wrapfigure if I could just put `after=\somecommand` in the tcolorbox options instead.

Also it's not obvious (to me) that combining `wrapfig` and `tcolorbox` would be unproblematic.

Comment: Isn't the example on page 74, `tcolorbox` 3.61. documentation something you wan't to achieve?

Comment: Given that you found nothing in the manual to suggest the package can do this, why do you nonetheless think the package can do it? Sorry, but this sounds very much like 'I've been through the instructions for the food processor and I don't see any evidence that it can cook food, but do I really need to use a cooker as well? I'd prefer to do everything with the food processor. So, how can I cook food with the food processor?'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I take it that the OP doesn't want the text to be within the box. The desiderata is to wrap body text around the `tcolorbox`. As if with `wrapfig`. But not only does the OP not want to use `wrapfig` (for unspecified reasons). The OP wants to use `tcolorbox` to do this. If that's right, then this is a feature request to the `tcolorbox` maintainer, IMHO, and so off-topic.

Comment: @cfr: That example is in the box, true, but I assume this could be modified, with `savelowerto` or something similar

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If it is really just text on the right of the box which is needed, that's true. (Don't even need `tcolorbox`'s facilities for that - a couple of `minipage`s would do it.) But the image the OP linked to shows text flowing around the box and that is different. (Unless you break the text manually into pieces, of course.)

Comment: @cfr: I think, it will require manual interaction anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why? `wrapfig` (or one of the other packages which offers something similar) should be able to flow text around the box just as it can around other boxed material. It isn't as though it is a list or something which needs to be flowed. Am I just not seeing the problem?

Comment: @cfr: I referred to a solution involving `tcolorbox`. I am aware about the `wrapfig` package ;-) If it's not possible with `tcolorbox`, alright, but I think there might be some ways. I was thinking recently also about writing some code for such stuff, but I did not try so far. But I've no time right now or during the next days

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That sounds great. But `tcolorbox` does not support this as it stands. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you asked for a non-`wrapfig` answer, though it is unclear why.  They can work together.  More importantly, I think, is that `tcolorbox` doesn't care much about how things outside the "colorboxes" look or behave, while `wrapfig` only cares about wrapping things around other things....

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum, wrapfig}
% change "top" vertical spacing in wrapfig
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Furst}
\subsection{Ok}

%Defining a newtcolorbox to be a standard box for all examples in the text:
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number
within=section]{phbox}[1][]{skin=bicolor,
  title=Figure~\thetcbcounter,#1,
  size=title,colback=white,colbacklower=black!10!white}


Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{r}[0pt]{5cm}
\begin{phbox}[label={fig:label},width=\linewidth]
\tcbincludepdf[scale=1,size=tight,opacityframe=0]{example-image.pdf}
\tcblower
Here is a bunch of text to explain a figure.
\end{phbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere

\end{document}
```

[image: wrapfig+tcolorbox]

Comment: That's the answer I would have given myself :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm -- Ah, high praise indeed!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution without using the `wrapfig` package. The idea is to define a macro `\newcommand{\MyWrapFigure}` with two arguments; the first is the figure and the second is the wrapping text. The macro calculates the dimensions of the figure and indents the text horizontally and vertically, accordingly.

Caution should be taken, however, when using such macros with, for example, `\hangindent`. It will not work for all situations out of the box. Messing with `\hangindent` in LaTeX is dangerous: list environments use `\parshape` that overrides it. You can use `\leftskip` instead.

The macro used here is by no means complete and can be much improved up on, but, this is at least a first step in getting rid of `wrapfig`. I hope it helps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc}

\newcommand{\MyWrapFigure}[2]{%
\newlength\picwidth
\newlength\picheight
\settowidth\picwidth{#1}
\settoheight\picheight{#1}
\newcount\countA
\countA=\picheight
\divide\countA by \baselineskip
\advance\countA by 2%
\newlength\heightT
\settoheight\heightT{\mbox{T}}%

% set the picture box
\noindent\raisebox{-\picheight+\heightT-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{#1}%

\setlength{\hangindent}{\picwidth+1em}
\hangafter-\countA
\let\OrigPar=\par% save the original \par command
\edef\par{\hfil\break\indent}
% now place the text
\noindent
#2%
\relax\let\par=\OrigPar\par
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{Furst}
\subsection{Ok}

%Defining a newtcolorbox to be a standard box for all examples in the text:
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{phbox}[1][]{skin=bicolor,title=Figure~\thetcbcounter,#1,size=title,colback=white,colbacklower=black!10!white}

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
\MyWrapFigure{%
\begin{phbox}[label={fig:label},halign=center,width=\linewidth/2]
\tcbincludepdf[scale=1,size=tight,opacityframe=0]{example-image.pdf}
\tcblower
Here is a bunch of text to explain a figure.
\end{phbox}
}
{%
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type this out. I should have clarified that I was asking if there is an obvious way to do it with tcolorbox. But since it seems there isn't, I'll just have to use wrapfig.