# Box with shadow on right hand side of paragraph

Tags: boxes

Is it possible to draw a box shown in this image which reduces the right margin of a paragraph it displays along side and adjusts its own height to the height of the paragraph?

Something like this perhaps?

```
\signaturebox{

... paragraph here ...

}
```

Here is what I am trying to reproduce...
[image]

Comment: Such a box can be drawn with TikZ and included with `wrapfig` into text (if I correctly  understand the question and given figure) or be put into margin of text. To be more specific, you need provide a code which tried so far, as already suggest Kurt.

Comment: Welcome to this location in virtual space-time.

Comment: That box hasn't adjusted its height to the paragraph height. Also, do you really want to reproduce that? It can be quite hard to make TeX produce output which is really ugly, although `philosophy.sty` is not a bad start.

Comment: You mean sort of like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255084/8528)? If so, I think this question is largely a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the feedback above, what I wanted to do can be accomplished using something **similar** this...

```
 \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[10mm]{50mm}
     \footnotesize
     \begin{tcolorbox}[
                 title={\hfill Important},
                 after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{NB!}},
                 width=\linewidth,
                 size=small,
                 opacitytext=1, opacityframe=0.75, opacitybacktitle=0.75,
                 enhanced, drop fuzzy shadow=black
         ]
         Initialled here as proof that your attention has been drawn to these provisions, and you consent to the contents thereof:
          \tcblower
         Initial:.......
     \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{wrapfigure}
```

Which results in...
[image]